# using "at" to run python script at a specific time not working

Tags: 16.04, python, automation

I am trying to run [this script](https://github.com/webrender/campsite-checker) at 7am PST every morning.

The command I am using in testing is:

```
echo "python checker.py" | at 8:40 PM
```

Which fails.

When I check the `at -c`log I get the following message:

```
root@black:~/Documents/projects/pytests/campsite-checker# at -c 23
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=0 gid=0
# mail root 0
umask 22
USER=root; export USER
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01\;34:ln=01\;36:mh=00:pi=40\;33:so=01\;35:do=01\;35:bd=40\;33\;01:cd=40\;33\;01:or=40\;31\;01:mi=00:su=37\;41:sg=30\;43:ca=30\;41:tw=30\;42:ow=34\;42:st=37\;44:ex=01\;32:\*.tar=01\;31:\*.tgz=01\;31:\*.arc=01\;31:\*.arj=01\;31:\*.taz=01\;31:\*.lha=01\;31:\*.lz4=01\;31:\*.lzh=01\;31:\*.lzma=01\;31:\*.tlz=01\;31:\*.txz=01\;31:\*.tzo=01\;31:\*.t7z=01\;31:\*.zip=01\;31:\*.z=01\;31:\*.Z=01\;31:\*.dz=01\;31:\*.gz=01\;31:\*.lrz=01\;31:\*.lz=01\;31:\*.lzo=01\;31:\*.xz=01\;31:\*.bz2=01\;31:\*.bz=01\;31:\*.tbz=01\;31:\*.tbz2=01\;31:\*.tz=01\;31:\*.deb=01\;31:\*.rpm=01\;31:\*.jar=01\;31:\*.war=01\;31:\*.ear=01\;31:\*.sar=01\;31:\*.rar=01\;31:\*.alz=01\;31:\*.ace=01\;31:\*.zoo=01\;31:\*.cpio=01\;31:\*.7z=01\;31:\*.rz=01\;31:\*.cab=01\;31:\*.jpg=01\;35:\*.jpeg=01\;35:\*.gif=01\;35:\*.bmp=01\;35:\*.pbm=01\;35:\*.pgm=01\;35:\*.ppm=01\;35:\*.tga=01\;35:\*.xbm=01\;35:\*.xpm=01\;35:\*.tif=01\;35:\*.tiff=01\;35:\*.png=01\;35:\*.svg=01\;35:\*.svgz=01\;35:\*.mng=01\;35:\*.pcx=01\;35:\*.mov=01\;35:\*.mpg=01\;35:\*.mpeg=01\;35:\*.m2v=01\;35:\*.mkv=01\;35:\*.webm=01\;35:\*.ogm=01\;35:\*.mp4=01\;35:\*.m4v=01\;35:\*.mp4v=01\;35:\*.vob=01\;35:\*.qt=01\;35:\*.nuv=01\;35:\*.wmv=01\;35:\*.asf=01\;35:\*.rm=01\;35:\*.rmvb=01\;35:\*.flc=01\;35:\*.avi=01\;35:\*.fli=01\;35:\*.flv=01\;35:\*.gl=01\;35:\*.dl=01\;35:\*.xcf=01\;35:\*.xwd=01\;35:\*.yuv=01\;35:\*.cgm=01\;35:\*.emf=01\;35:\*.ogv=01\;35:\*.ogx=01\;35:\*.aac=00\;36:\*.au=00\;36:\*.flac=00\;36:\*.m4a=00\;36:\*.mid=00\;36:\*.midi=00\;36:\*.mka=00\;36:\*.mp3=00\;36:\*.mpc=00\;36:\*.ogg=00\;36:\*.ra=00\;36:\*.wav=00\;36:\*.oga=00\;36:\*.opus=00\;36:\*.spx=00\;36:\*.xspf=00\;36:; export LS_COLORS
SUDO_USER=black; export SUDO_USER
SUDO_UID=1000; export SUDO_UID
USERNAME=root; export USERNAME
MAIL=/var/mail/root; export MAIL
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin; export PATH
PWD=/home/black/Documents/projects/pytests/campsite-checker; export PWD
LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG
SHLVL=1; export SHLVL
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash; export SUDO_COMMAND
HOME=/home/black; export HOME
LANGUAGE=en_US; export LANGUAGE
LOGNAME=root; export LOGNAME
LESSOPEN=\|\ /usr/bin/lesspipe\ %s; export LESSOPEN
SUDO_GID=1000; export SUDO_GID
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe\ %s\ %s; export LESSCLOSE
XAUTHORITY=/home/black/.Xauthority; export XAUTHORITY
OLDPWD=/home/black/Documents/projects/pytests; export OLDPWD
cd /home/black/Documents/projects/pytests/campsite\-checker || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
python checker.py
```

Which after lots of Google for key works I still do not know what it means?

Comment: To run a command at 7am PST *every morning* you will want `cron` -
 not `at`

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck.
1. Tried three different combinations in the crontab file

file: env EDITOR=nano crontab -e

* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 FireFox
00 08 * * * root python /home/black/Documents/projects/pytests/campsite-checker/checker.py



* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 FireFox
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/black/Documents/projects/pytests/campsite-checker/checker.py 


* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 FireFox
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/black/Documents/projects/pytests/campsite-checker/checker.py

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the execution environment being set up; it's not an error message.

If there were error messages, they would have been emailed to root. Check your root email?

Comment: Ok, not an error message. Given the above information, what are your thoughts on what is causing the failure?